# Dateframe interpolate not working in Panda + multidimensional interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

multidimensional interpolation with dataframe not working

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'CCY_CODE': ['SGD','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','EUR','EUR','EUR','EUR','EUR','EUR','USD'],
            'END_DATE': ['16/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018',
                        '17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018','17/03/2018'],
            'STRIKE':[0.005,0.01,0.015,0.02,0.025,0.03,0.035,0.04,0.045,0.05,0.55,0.06,0.065,0.07],
            'VOLATILITY':[np.nan,np.nan,0.3424,np.nan,0.2617,0.2414,np.nan,np.nan,0.215,0.212,0.2103,np.nan,0.2092,np.nan]
           }
df_volsurface = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns = ['CCY_CODE','END_DATE','STRIKE','VOLATILITY'])
df_volsurface['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_volsurface['END_DATE'])
df_volsurface.interpolate(method='akima',limit_direction='both')
```

Output:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>CCY_CODE</th><th>END_DATE</th><th>STRIKE</th><th>VOLATILITY</th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>SGD</td><td>3/16/2018</td><td>0.005</td><td>NaN</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.01</td><td>NaN</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.015</td><td>0.3424</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.02</td><td>0.296358</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.025</td><td>0.2617</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.03</td><td>0.2414</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.035</td><td>0.230295</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.04</td><td>0.220911</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.045</td><td>0.215</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.05</td><td>0.212</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.55</td><td>0.2103</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.06</td><td>0.209471</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.065</td><td>0.2092</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.07</td><td>NaN</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Expected Result:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>CCY_CODE</th><th>END_DATE</th><th>STRIKE</th><th>VOLATILITY</th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>SGD</td><td>3/16/2018</td><td>0.005</td><td>NaN</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.01</td><td>Expected some logical value</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.015</td><td>0.3424</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.02</td><td>0.296358</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.025</td><td>0.2617</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.03</td><td>0.2414</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.035</td><td>0.230295</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.04</td><td>0.220911</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.045</td><td>0.215</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.05</td><td>0.212</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.55</td><td>0.2103</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.06</td><td>0.209471</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.065</td><td>0.2092</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.07</td><td>Expected some logical value</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Linear interpolation methods gives copy last available values to all backward and forward missing value without considering ccy_code

```
df_volsurface.interpolate(method='linear',limit_direction='both')
```

Output:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>CCY_CODE</th><th>END_DATE</th><th>STRIKE</th><th>VOLATILITY</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>SGD</td><td>3/16/2018</td><td>0.005</td><td>0.3424</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.01</td><td>0.3424</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.015</td><td>0.3424</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.02</td><td>0.30205</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.025</td><td>0.2617</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.03</td><td>0.2414</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.035</td><td>0.2326</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.04</td><td>0.2238</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.045</td><td>0.215</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.05</td><td>0.212</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.55</td><td>0.2103</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.06</td><td>0.20975</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>EUR</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.065</td><td>0.2092</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>USD</td><td>3/17/2018</td><td>0.07</td><td>0.2092</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dataframe `df_volsurface` before you call interpolate?

Comment: Hi WolfgangK, Thanks for helping on this. Updated as requested.

Comment: Judging from the picture you posted, there are no missing data. If you interpolate between two values that are both 0, the result will still be 0. As a general hint, make it easy for us to help you: it would be great to have the data sample in a form we can copy and paste to reproduce your error. Also, show the result you expected. Since nobody has your csv files, the code for data preparation is mostly meaningless for others. Maybe take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: WolfgangK, As suggested I changed my question. Also, Thanks for earlier comment about 0. 0 needs to convert NaN before interpolation which now works but have some issues as posted. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that there is a typo in your `'STRIKE'` column (0.55 should be 0.055).

Comment: Should interpolation only be carried out within the same `CCY_CODE`? E.g. for `USD` the `'STRIKE'` data points would be `[0.01,0.015,0.02,0.025,0.03,0.035,0.07]`?

Comment: Should it also consider `END_DATE`? Just in case your real data has a wider range of dates.

Comment: Yes, only for same ccy_code, it shouldn't consider other ccy_code. For example SGD should remain NaN after interpolation because there is no data points being. Even USD last row (13) should interpolated based on previous USD data point row 5 or 6, not on EUR row 12.

Yes very good point about end_date, I've end_date and one more column called scenarios_id e.g. 1 or 2. So the points which I try to understand and explore is how multidimensional interpolation works in panda or even in Python where there multiple columns dependency for interpolation. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: I mean i’ve two requirements a.) Interpolate volatility based on Scenario_id, end_date, ccy_code, strike columns b.) separately Interpolate Interest Rate based on Scenario_id , start_date, end_date and ccy_code. Both interpolations are independents. But the key is how to do multidensions InterP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to point out that this is still onedimensional interpolation. We have one independent variable (`'STRIKE'`) and one dependent variable ('`VOLATILITY'`). Interpolation is done for different conditions, e.g. for each day, each currency, each scenario, etc. The following is an example of how the interpolation can be done based on `'END_DATE'` and '`CCY_CODE'`.

```
# set all the conditions as index
df_volsurface.set_index(['END_DATE', 'CCY_CODE', 'STRIKE'], inplace=True)
df_volsurface.sort_index(level=['END_DATE', 'CCY_CODE', 'STRIKE'], inplace=True)
# create separate columns for all criteria except the independent variable
df_volsurface = df_volsurface.unstack(level=['END_DATE', 'CCY_CODE'])
for ccy in df_volsurface:
    indices = df_volsurface[ccy].notna()
    if not any(indices):
        continue  # we are not interested in a column with only NaN
    x = df_volsurface.index.get_level_values(level='STRIKE')  # independent var
    y = df_volsurface[ccy]  # dependent var
    # create interpolation function
    f_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x[indices], y[indices], kind='linear', 
                            bounds_error=False, fill_value='extrapolate')
    df_volsurface['VOL_INTERP', ccy[1], ccy[2]] = f_interp(x)
print(df_volsurface)
```

The interpolation for the other conditions should work analogously. This is the resulting DataFrame:

```
         VOLATILITY                    VOL_INTERP         
END_DATE 2018-03-16 2018-03-17         2018-03-17         
CCY_CODE        SGD        EUR     USD        EUR      USD
STRIKE                                                    
0.005           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.23900  0.42310
0.010           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.23600  0.38275
0.015           NaN        NaN  0.3424    0.23300  0.34240
0.020           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.23000  0.30205
0.025           NaN        NaN  0.2617    0.22700  0.26170
0.030           NaN        NaN  0.2414    0.22400  0.24140
0.035           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.22100  0.22110
0.040           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.21800  0.20080
0.045           NaN     0.2150     NaN    0.21500  0.18050
0.050           NaN     0.2120     NaN    0.21200  0.16020
0.055           NaN     0.2103     NaN    0.21030  0.13990
0.060           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.20975  0.11960
0.065           NaN     0.2092     NaN    0.20920  0.09930
0.070           NaN        NaN     NaN    0.20865  0.07900
```

Use `df_volsurface.stack()` to return to a multiindex of your choice. There are also several `pandas` interpolation methods to choose from. However, I have not found a satisfactory solution for your problem using `method='akima'` because it only interpolates between the given data points, but does not seem to extrapolate beyond.

Comment: Do we need to Groupby using `CCY_CODE` column before interpolation?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Do you need separate interpolation for each currency? Your "expected output" doesn't show it like that, so I didn't bother. Can you go into some more detail on what you are trying to do and update your question accordingly?

Comment: In the question, user9930820 mentioned that `Linear interpolation methods gives copy last available values to all backward and forward missing value without considering ccy_code`. So I thought, user9930820 wants to consider ccy_code for interpolation.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra You are probably right. To me it looked as if OP's main concern was that there was either no extrapolation with `akima` method or that values are just being repeated with `linear`.

Comment: @AbhisekMishra updated above question list with more details. I prefer Akima as it match with expected result however I also want to learn how do multidemsional Interpolation e.g given t, u, v, x, y interpolate z without aggregate data.